# is it possible downloading application from my web site

Tags: android

As you understand, I will download application from my server if user click on the download link.  And of course for installing, user will accept in irder to install it. Thus, I wonder ;

- Is it possible to download package from my server? If yes how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Make sure you have your server configured to use the appropriate mime type.

```
AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk
```

OR

```
<a href="apk location" type="application/vnd.android.package-archive">Download App</a>
```

To download the apk in your app, you can use the my open source library [here](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AppaholicsUpdateChecker/). While it is meant for checking for and downloading updates, you can use it to download other apk files (or any other file at all) as well.

In your Activity add the following code to your onCreate(). If you don't want toast notifications, change the second parameter to `false`:

```
UpdateChecker checker = new UpdateChecker(this, true);
```

Then, use the following to download and install the update. Note that this will show a progress dialog while downloading:

```
checker.downloadAndInstall("URL with http:// to the location of the update apk");
```

Comment: I can use your code to download other application(s)  via help of my application. Am I understand right?

Comment: do I need to change something in your library?

Comment: @user1993428 Nope. I'll add sample code in a minute to show you how to use it

Comment: @user1993428 I've added sample code. Make sure to put the library in the /libs folder.

Answer (score 1):

If the Android framework has downloaded an .apk file it will ask you if you want to install it. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to download the apk file:

```
String fileName="yourApk.apk";
try 
{
    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath()+"/DownloadedApk/");
    if(dir.exists()==false) 
    {
         dir.mkdirs();
    }
    URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/apk/yourApk.apk"); 
    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir+"/"+fileName);
    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    long lenghtOfFile=ucon.getContentLength();
    int count = 0;
    long total = 0;
    int progress = 0;
    while (((count=is.read(data)) != -1))
    {
        total += count;
        int progress_temp = (int) ((int)total*100/lenghtOfFile);
        if(progress_temp%10 == 0 && progress != progress_temp)
        {
            progress = progress_temp;
            publishProgress(progress);    
        }
        fos.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    is.close();
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) 
{
    Log.d("DownloadManager", "Error: " + e);
}
```